# reset a dynamic array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a function that pushes a dynamic amount of numbers into an array when I click a button, the code looks like this:

```
$('#calculate').click(function(e) {

var foo = $(".foo"),
    A = [],
    B = [];

    //Push values
foo.each(function(){
  var $t = $(this),
    num = $t.val(),
    xnum = num * 2.42;
  A.push(xnum);
  B.push(num);
});

//more stuff down here... 
//.ajax() to run and print a calculation
```

I'm getting these values from `<select>` menus and then I have a button that removes the `<select>` menu that it accompanies using the `.empty()` function...

I run into a problem when I calculate, THEN delete one of the `<select>` menus and recalculate... The value from the deleted `<select>` is still included in my calculation!

I figured the easiest way to reset the array would be to use:

```
A.length = 0;
B.length = 0;
```

But for some reason these aren't reseting the arrays and the old values are still included in the new calculation...

Is there a better way I can totally clear the array before I start pushing items into it?

Comment: Seems to be the easiest: `A = []`.

Comment: @VisioN aren't I already doing that in the first few lines under `var foo = $(".foo")`

Comment: OK. Can you make a JSFiddle demo? That will be easier to answer.

Comment: I have a ton of code in my actual application... I could simplify it down though... give me a couple minutes! haha

Comment: @VisioN here it is! http://jsfiddle.net/UFvu5/1/

Comment: @VisioN the right answer is below!

Comment: @tdun **AVOID** having multiple `ID` in a single page! (#remove) Use `class` instead.

Comment: O yea! thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "#remove", function() {
    $this=$(this);
    $this.parent('.foowrap').fadeOut(function() {
        $this.parent('.foowrap').empty();
    });
});
```

**Update:** Use class `.remove` instead of  id `#remove`, id meant to be unique.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UFvu5/2/).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! Why does this fix it? Just adding in `$this=$(this);` changed it all...???

Comment: You've used `$(this)` inside the callback function, wrong variable scope.

Comment: @tdun look for your answer to my comment at david's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the other answer to be more like this:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.foowrap').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).empty();
  });
});
```

Notice, it avoids two calls to `parent` and the global variable and adds the missing semicolon.

EDIT: saw you had 2 elements with the same `id` so changed my code to assume you will change `remove` to a `class`.

Comment: Actually ... it's not a *two calls to parent* but the real issue was that the second one: `$(this).parent('.foowrap')` was searching for a `.foowrap` parent of `.foowrap` that was actually unexistant - and the method `.empty()` was never pointing to the right parent.

Comment: @Roko -- I know the other answer solves it; I was merely improving upon that answer, which is technically correct but is not perfect.

Comment: Both of the `$(this)` refer to the `.remove` button and my function is emptying the entire `.foowrap`, then each of the `.parent()` call to the `.foowrap` containing the remove button- right?

Comment: @tdun -- No, the first `$(this)` refers to the `remove` button; the second `$(this)` refers to `.foowrap` div.